# In UILabel dotted line is show front in iOS ?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to show the dotted line in front of the text (Same as Apple default Keypad Label).

Like as (....hi)

Comment: u mean like this "hi..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 6 use `NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead` of [NSLineBreakMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLineBreakMode).

From the docs:

> NSLineBreakByTruncatingHead The line is displayed so that the end fits
>   in the container and the missing text at the beginning of the line is
>   indicated by an ellipsis glyph. Although this mode works for multiline
>   text, it is more often used for single line text.

For iOS < 6 you can use `UILineBreakModeHeadTruncation` of [UILineBreakMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#).

Answer (score 0):

Dot will come automatically. if your text is big compare to label size. Then dot will come

automatically.

Comment: Or If my above answer not helps you then try: label1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;

Comment: Don't give label width too much...Then text will automatically show in dotted format.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder: Line Break Mode -> Truncate Head